# How can we mount a file as read-only in Linux through Go?

Tags: linux, go, mount, unmount

I want to know how can we mount an file as read-only in Linux CentOS 7 Server through Golang. I have tried syscall but that doesn't work, syscall mounts the file but as read-write i have tried to give ro argument in the data but still it's mounting as read-write.
Here is my go code:

```
syscall.Mount(src, dst, "auto", syscall.MS_BIND, "ro")
```

You can see I have given ***ro*** argument in the data, i have also tried to give only **r** and **readonly** and also **read-only** but none of them works, when i compile the go file and execute it and then when i check /etc/mtab then i am getting this output :

```
cat /etc/mtab | grep "firewall"
/dev/vda1 /root/firewall.txt ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv1,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
```

Here you can see that firewall.txt is mounted as **rw** means **read-write**

I want to mount it as read-only , can anyone help me how can i do that in Golang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced similar issue, It was fixed by setting fstype as **bind** and flags as **MS_REMOUNT** **MS_RDONLY** and **MS_BIND** . You can use these codes:

```
syscall.Mount(source, destination, "bind", syscall.MS_REMOUNT|syscall.MS_RDONLY|syscall.MS_BIND, "")
```

Comment: awesome, it worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Read-only mode is defined by the syscall flag [`MS_RDONLY`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html), which is also defined in the [syscall package](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#pkg-constants). So the call should be:

```
syscall.Mount(src, dst, "auto", syscall.MS_BIND | syscall.MS_RDONLY, "")
```

Comment: Still the issue is same, the file is mounting as read write not read only